# Automation Test Architecture

Tags: testing, architecture, automation, software-design

We have 5 Different Environments and all of them having Different code and different versions and we have to maintain all of them with up to date code. Right now I'm using all different branch from TFS for all the environments and we have configure URL for each of them in all branches but now it is hard to maintain. Can any one suggest me any good Structure for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You almost perfectly describe the approach used in [Continuous delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). In the most common way it's considered that you'll have to *Only Build Your Binaries Once*. One important corollary of this principle is that it must be possible to deploy these binaries to every environment. This forces you to separate code, which remains the same between environments, and **configuration, which differs between environments**. This, in turn, will lead you to managing your configuration correctly, applying a gentle pressure towards better-structured build systems. You can use such practices as disk imaging and virtualization, and tools like Puppet and InstallShield along with a version control repository, to manage your environments' configuration.

> We have 5 Different Environments

Each of these environments can be more or less production-like and have their own unique configuration. Your CI server should be configured to watch your version control system, check out or update your source code every time a change is made to it, run the automated build process, and store the binaries on the filesystem where they are accessible to the whole team via the CI server's user interface. As shown here:

[image]

you can store your environments configuration scripts in a separate/shared DB and just load them from there when needed.